# How to export Windows Server logs from Event Viewer GUI

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, events, event-viewer

I tried to export different logs from Windows Event Viewer however in many cases, I did get values (= they are codes for some columns values) from the XML presented vue instead of values represented in the Event Viewer GUI interface. so please could you give me a way to get the data from the GUI interface or another way to interact with Windows API to get the necessary mapping values of those codes to their string values?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I will be happy with your help.

I did use PowerShell scripts but I did find that sometimes it gives string values for some columns, and in other cases it return  code values instead so I did need to find a way to map them but it's not possible to do the  mapping for  certain columns within specific values and especially doing it manually.
So I want to find way to get the data presented in the Event Viewer GUI like it's. or  a way to get an automatic mapping for example using Windows API.
If there is any other solution am keen to learn about it.
Please if any one could help me I will be very glad for it's help
Thank you again.

Comment: "I did use PowerShell scripts" - show us your code :)